# Is it possible to change Header data dynamically in HTTP header

Tags: java, rest, http, jax-rs

I got an issue in my workplace . I am fetching some customer data using REST web services and sending customer id in HTTP header and code will fetch the data and return me the result .
But something unusual happened customer id got changed dynamically and i got an error no customer found.

For example: 2 customer login their account at same time , and both are fetching a bit different URI e.g. customer c1 is fetching :a/{b}/c and customer c2 is fetching a/ . both have unique session in and different customer id.

Here when c1 is calling URI   a/{b}/c then somehow in header of c1 got changed and customer id of c1 becomes c2(changed with c2 id) and we get invalid customer id error.

We are not able to reproduce this scenario at all. it happened only once.

I wanted to know the possible reasons, how can it be possible to change the customer id dynamically?

Comment: This is the sort of question that you ask the development team that built that service and/or maintain it.  Because it's possible you found a bug.  But it's domain knowledge that I doubt any one here will be able to help you with unless we had way more information than provided here.

Comment: @Razzle you are right data is not sufficient but question is "Is it possible that it can be change dynamically ?" i am not looking for exact answer .I just want to know if it possible and what are the scenarios where it can be possible that if i am sending an request and passing some data in HTTP header and extracting it other end then can header content  be changed in between?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an HTTPS connection end-to-end then it is accepted that the contents could not have be modified *given today's computing power*.

Some load balancers do not inspect traffic and route traffic based on only minimal information (source IP, target IP, etc).

Others terminate the SSL connection at the load balancer so that the headers and other contents can be inspected to make routing decisions.  It is possible that this kind of **load balancer** changed the customer id in your situation, perhaps due to a corrupted session in the load balancer memory.  Or your setup might have a **reverse proxy**.  Any computer along the path which **terminates SSL** could also have changed the customer id.

As well, the **endpoint** itself that you are connecting to might have corrupted customer id in its session, and replied to you a response with the incorrect customer id.  All of these would be considered a bug.

Comment: Our team once maintained a (rarely used) internal web service that worked fine when used by one customer at a time. But when two customers were doing a similar thing at the same time, then one customer's session would be garbled -- customer 2 would see some of customer 1's state. This is a horrible bug. So, if you're hunting for any code smells in your service, sniff for any leaks of **session data** into **static/global variables**